# Magento 2 : How to pass variable to controller from observer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, event-observer, variables

I am not able to pass variables to controller from my observer file.
Below is the code for observer:

```
 class Sendtogateway implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
        {
          protected $_responseFactory;
          protected $_url;
          protected $order;
            protected $logger;

            public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
            \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface
            ){
                $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
            $this->_url = $url;
            $this->order = $order;
                $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
            }

          public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
          {
            $id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
            $orderdetail = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($id);
            $url = "affrikpay/index/index/id/".$id;
            $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl($url);
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
            $this->logger->debug('done');
          }

        }
```

And calling variable in controller with

```
     public function execute()
        {      
           $id = $this->request->getParam('id');      
           $this->logger->debug($id);
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't call a controller in your observer. That might be the cause of your problem. Can you give me more context of the exact problem?

Comment: Thanks for your interest David , I am able to redirect to controller from observer but was not able to send the order id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting variable from param is not a reliable way, you should try using session, since you seem to be dealing with checkout use checkout session like following ;

Inject `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` into observer's constructor and set your variable like ;

```
$this->_checkoutSession->setVariableName('value');
```

you can get it on controller like following ;

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Demo;


class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {

        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $varValue = $this->_checkoutSession->getVariableName();
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

If you do want to do it using params , you are passing them wrongly,
remove `$url = "affrikpay/index/index/id/".$id;` and use following in place of `$customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl($url);`

```
$query = ['id' => $id];
$customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('affrikpay/index/index',['_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $query]);
```

Comment: Thanks Neo, well I am using place order after observer so I think checkout session will be lost after place order. However I am able to get last order id in observer. I am trying to pass this order id to controller. Though checkout session I am not sure will work but yeah session is a good idea I will create my on session variable. Thanks for guiding me

Comment: I have used session in a similar situation, so I suggested this.

Comment: @AshishSharma please check updated answer

Comment: I just want to confirm I am using observer to call the controller and send order detail from controller to payment gateway. Is observer a good choice or we can call controller with order id directly from knockout js etc. if there is any possibility please help :)

Comment: session brought in value to controller thanks so much. U r champ 100 likes